# Is it possible to use difftime function in R with years ONLY (i.e. no DD/MM)?

Tags: r

For example:

| Year A | Year B |
| --- | --- |
| 1990 | 2021 |
| 1980 | 2021 |

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your expected output ? `df$YearB - df$YearA` would work ?

Comment: Does the comment above not answer your question? What is the difference between treating the variable as an integer and treating it as a year?

Answer (score 0):

It depends of what you expect.

If you only want to use the `difftime()` function with date objects composed only of years (as below), it will work (it will set the day and month to the ones of today for the calculation).

```
> a = as.Date("2021", format("%Y"))
> b = as.Date("2010", format("%Y"))
> difftime(a,b)
```

```
Time difference of 4018 days
```

But if you want to get the difference in year, it is not possible, as the function documentation clearly state that the return value unit must be: *units = c("auto", "secs", "mins", "hours", "days", "weeks")*

You might find better way to handle date/time data with the `lubridate` package.

Answer (score 0):

*difftime* requests a date object to be used, I tried reproducing this using only years but was unable to.

Why not simply use absolute value (*abs()*)If you're only interested in year difference?

as an example so you can see the difference added to a new column:

```
Year_A <- c(1990, 1980)
Year_B <- c(2021, 2021)

df <- data.frame(Year_A, Year_B)

df$diff <- abs(Year_A - Year_B)
```

P.S I noticed the answer above me was added while I was answering and I can't comment to it due to low rep, i see you can't use "years" as a unit value there, the biggest one being weeks, but you can manipulate that from days/weeks to years if that's what you're after.

Comment: Thanks this worked wonderfully. Much appreciated